# Plot or highlight additional values in facet wrap graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have some time series data, I've used a few functions to find specific x,y coordinates and wish to have them highlighted on the facet plot I've created. Not even sure if it's possible.

```
# create sample data
t<-seq(1:100)
a<-rnorm(1:100)
b<-rnorm(1:100)
c<-rnorm(1:100)
g <-as.data.frame(cbind(t,a,b,c))
g <- melt(g,id="t")

# current facet graph
ggplot(g,aes(x=t,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

This looks along the lines of what I've got right now. But I've also got the additional data below, which is a dataframe of x,y coordinates.

```
# sample data with x,y coords
x1 <- c(10,11,15)
y1 <- c(5,6,9)
x2 <- c(50,41,35)
y2 <- c(25,27,19)
xy<-rbind(x1,y1,x2,y2)
colnames(xy)<-c("a","b","c")
```

I'm not sure how to make this happen. I'd like the coordinates to be graphed in their individual plots.

Comment: What's the relation between row names, columm names and cell values of `xy` and the values of `g`? I don't understand what the resulting graph should look like.

Comment: Your second dataset needs to be in a different format.  You'll want a column that represents `variable` with values "a", "b", or "c".  And then you want a column for the x coordinates and a column for the y coordinates.

Comment: per @aosmith `#library(tidyverse) 
data.frame(x = c(10,11,15,50,41,35),y = c(5,6,9,25,27,19),id=c(rep('1',3), rep('2',3)) ,var=c('a','b','c')) %>%    ggplot(aes(x,y, color=id))+
   geom_point()+ 
   facet_wrap(~var)`

Comment: thanks the format of my data is definitely the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help above, as you guys suspected the format of my data was incorrect. I'm still a novice and so collecting and formatting the data is often not as straightforward.

```
#the format of my 'primary' dataframe
t<-seq(1:100)
a<-rnorm(1:100)
b<-rnorm(1:100)
c<-rnorm(1:100)
g <-as.data.frame(cbind(t,a,b,c))
g <- melt(g,id="t")

#and then converting the original dataframe above to something that matches
xy<-data.frame(t = c(10,11,15,50,41,35),variable=c('a','b','c'),value = c(5,6,9,25,27,19))
```

as soon as I converted the df to the correct format it became much easier to fiddle around with.

```
ggplot(g,aes(x=t,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=xy,size=4) +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

The below picture shows the result. Perhaps a better title to the question would be **Plot multiple dataframes on a single facet**

[image: This is what I was looking for]